# How to get multiple "last values" for different criteria from a single column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, greatest-n-per-group

Our `interest_log` table stores events of users expressing interest on `foo`.

```
CREATE TABLE interest_log (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

    user_id bigint REFERENCES foo_user(id),
    foo_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES foo(id),

    action varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(300) -- nullable
);
```

Some of the available `action`s are:

`VIEW`, `FAVOR`, `UNFAVOR`, `DISMISS`, and `UNDISMISS`.

I want to create a `materialized view` that provides the latest state of whether a user favors or dismisses a `foo`.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW interest
AS
SELECT
    il.user_id,
    il.foo_id,
    ??? AS is_dismissed,
    ??? AS is_favored
FROM
    interest_log AS il,
WHERE
    ???
```

I came up with this query to select `is_dismissed` - but it feels too complicated and I don't see how I can combine it with fetching the latest `favored` state as well.

```
SELECT
  il.action = 'DISMISS' AS is_dismissed
FROM interest_log AS il
WHERE
  il.action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS')
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM interest_log AS il2
    WHERE
      il.action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS')
      AND il2.id < il.id
```

**What could the materialized view query look like and what fields/indexes should we add to make refreshs fast?**

postgres:10.11

Comment: Dear community, this question is not about timestamps (and the reasonable different opinions on where to use which format) but about selecting multiple differently aggregated fields in the same query. It is fine to simplify the timestamp for this issue and just use the `id` to determine which entry is the desired one. Thanks.

Comment: Fair point, it's not about `id` or `timestamp`. (I still second calls for a proper timestamp column.) It's about a tricky query, indexes and performance. We ask of you to provide basic information for performance questions. [See instructions here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) Most importantly, for this question: how many distinct actions, roughly how many users, how many interest_log, how many relevant actions per user, avg. row size in `interest_log` and `user`. Also: shall the MV contain a row for *every* combination of foo and user?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks. There are few distinct actions (5-10). Per `(user, foo)` there will be few (0-10) entries in the `interest_log`, most often 0 - so space-wise it is nice to not have a row for all combinations. The MV will be left joined to other queries to indicate which foos should be included (e.g. only the ones that have been favored) or when viewing foo's to display metrics such as 'how many users favored the specific foo'. We don't know the metrics for sure because it's an emerging project, so performance is not a big deal currently, but giving it a good first shot is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only few entries per `(user_id, foo_id)`, the query you have is typically faster this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, foo_id)
       user_id, foo_id
       action = 'DISMISS' AS is_dismissed
FROM   interest_log
ORDER  BY user_id, foo_id, id DESC
WHERE  action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS');
```

But this only produces rows for `(user_id, foo_id)` that actually have (un-)dismissed.

If there are relatively ***few*** rows per `(user_id, foo_id)` for both items of interest (`is_dismissed` and `is_favored`), just run a `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` on two of these queries to produce the set of all that either (un-)dismissed or (un-)favored:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, foo_id)
          user_id, foo_id
        , action = 'DISMISS' AS is_dismissed
   FROM   interest_log
   WHERE  action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS')
   ORDER  BY user_id, foo_id, id DESC
   ) d
FULL   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, foo_id)
          user_id, foo_id
        , action = 'FAVOR' AS is_favored
   FROM   interest_log
   WHERE  action IN ('FAVOR', 'UNFAVOR')
   ORDER  BY user_id, foo_id, id DESC
   ) f USING (user_id, foo_id);
```

About `DISTINCT ON` and *few* vs. *many*:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Support with two partial indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX interest_log_dismiss ON interest_log (user_id, foo_id, id DESC, action)
WHERE  action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS');

CREATE INDEX interest_log_favor ON interest_log (user_id, foo_id, id DESC, action)
WHERE  action IN ('FAVOR', 'UNFAVOR');
```

Or using a custom aggregate function `last()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.last_agg (anyelement, anyelement)
RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS 'SELECT $2';

CREATE AGGREGATE public.last(anyelement) (
  SFUNC = public.last_agg
, STYPE = anyelement
);
```

Then this simpler query does the same:

```
SELECT user_id, foo_id
     , last(action) FILTER (WHERE action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS')) = 'DISMISS' AS is_dismissed
     , last(action) FILTER (WHERE action IN ('FAVOR', 'UNFAVOR'))     = 'FAVOR'   AS is_favored
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   interest_log
   WHERE  action IN ('DISMISS', 'UNDISMISS', 'FAVOR', 'UNFAVOR')
   ORDER  BY user_id, foo_id, id
   ) sub
GROUP  BY user_id, foo_id;
```

Faster with the [additional module `first_last_agg`](https://pgxn.org/dist/first_last_agg/) providing a C implementation. See:

- [Calculating follower growth over time for each influencer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62164069/939860)

There are more ways (have a look at the linked answer), and depending on undisclosed information, different query styles may be (much) faster.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate a little on what exactly you mean by `If there are relatively few rows for both items of interest` (item = action? and "few rows" per `(user, foo)`  (few is correct) or few per `action` in total over all foo and user (there are many)?. And do you mean a `OR` or `XOR` with `all that either (un-)dismissed or (un-)favored`?

Comment: @Stuck: I clarified above and added a link with ample details.